# Using Safenet HASP in VisualStudio unit test

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, hasp

I have been using HASP 5.0 in my .Net 4.0 (VS2010, Win 7) application with no problems.

I am adding some new functionality and am trying to create unit tests for it.  I am not able to run code from the test project that logs into the hasp license.  After logging in with vendor code, I get HaspStatus.HaspDotNetDllBroken {652}.  The same code does run OK from the main project.

I copied the following files:

```
apidsp_windows.dll
apidsp_windows_x64.dll
hasp_net_windows_x64.dll
hasp_windows_NNNNN.dll (my client DLL)
hasp_windows_x64_114204.dll
```

into the test execution directory, and added a reference to hasp_net_windows.dll into the test project.

I also tried to have the problematic code in the test function (not the main code base) but have the same problem.

Any ideas

Comment: Does it compile in the Test projects? Can you provide a error stack? Does the Test and Main project run the same .NET profile? And referencing the same .NET assemblies?

Comment: It does compile in the Test project.  The two run in the Debug Profile.  The question about the references is interesting - I will play around a bit.

Comment: With profile I don't mean Debug or Release. I mean ASP.NET profile or Client profile and so on. One more thing: are they running the same .NET target framework (and version)?

Comment: Strangely I can not see the framework drop down list in the application tab of the properties screen, so I can not make sure.  And how do I find the profile?

Comment: Depends on how you VS is set-up, they should be available under Target framework. Here is a msdn page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh487283.aspx) on the topic. But it might not be related to your problem... Can you post you exception and stack trace as well?

Comment: There is no exception.  The HASP object returns a status that is not OK.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28025/discussion-between-gilshalit-and-jocke)